# How to add a border to SparkLine data?

Tags: reporting-services

How does one go about indicating a colored border in an Area Chart Sparkline, as seen in this example:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/sparklines-and-data-bars-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

I've been able to configure the light blue foreground, by setting the `Palette` property to `Custom` and adding the color `RGB(204,220,235)` to the `CustomPaletteColors` collection, but there doesn't seem to be a border-related property for the data series. I also tried adding several other colors to the collection, but that had no effect.

The border properties—`BorderColor`, `BorderStyle` and `BorderWidth`—operate on the cell, not the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it.

It's on the Series Properties dialog, here:

[image]